# Select more than time occurrence in ms sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table listed like this and i want to find out what are the display names that has repeated on the table, there are so many data that I cannot go manually, and tag names are different even though display names are same.

```
> tag name  display name
>     3_call    call
>     180_call  call
>     3_pass    pass
>     3_depp    deep
```

The table has so much data and I want to find out what are the display names has occurred more than one time.

:)

Answer (score 2):

To find out how many times each [display name] appears:

```
SELECT [display name], COUNT(*)
FROM <Table>
GROUP BY [display name]
```

To find [display names] that appear more than once:

```
SELECT [display name], COUNT(*)
FROM <Table>
GROUP BY [display name]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select displayname,count(*)
  from tablename
  group by displayname 
  having count(*) > 1
```